# Laravel on Heroku: Scheduled task

Tags: php, laravel, heroku

I working currently on a simple Reminder Laravel app for Heroku. I've written my API and everything works well. Now I want to run a scheduled task on Heroku.

Basically I'm looking for something to execute the following command on a separate dyno:

```
php EmailScheduler.php
```

or

```
php artisan schedule:emails
```

This command should be a long running process where e.g. each minute the same task is being executed over and over.

In this task I want to query my database and get all reminders that are due and send them as an email so I have to be able to access the business logic of my application like eloquent models.

I know about the scheduler add-on or about certain "cron" solutions but I would like a PHP only solution so just a long running script or task that might sleep most of the time and wake up each minute or so.

In Ruby (Rails) for example I could require the environment, thereby have access to my business logic and then fire up a timer task using the concurrent-ruby library.

I already tried to require the

```
bootstrap/autoload.php
bootstrap/app.php
```

files but it seems like I have to do more than just this, like boot the application.

How can I solve this using the Laravel framework and possibly other third-party libraries ?

Answer (score 0):

Task Scheduling in laravel is done by making a cron job. By defining a cron job, one can schedule a task to be excuted at a defind period. 
You follow the official documentation of laravel for scheduling: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/scheduling

Comment: thanks for your answer. Yes I know, but I want a PHP only solution, so I don't want to rely on cron (since I want to host in a cloud environment and "cron" might not be available in this way)

Answer (score 0):

In 2017, you indeed couldn't use cron on Heroku. As of 2021, you can use [Cron To Go](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/crontogo), an Heroku add-on, to set up a cron job that runs on one-off dynos in Heroku. Simply follow the guide [here](https://crontogo.com/blog/how-to-run-php-laravel-scheduled-jobs-on-heroku/) to run Laravel's scheduler once a minute.